# Deleting stored functions in PostgreSQL using VSCode

Tags: sql, postgresql, visual-studio-code

[image: vscode environment]

I think I have created a stored procedure using the following:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION select_all_employee_demographics()
RETURNS REFCURSOR
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    cur REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR SELECT * FROM EmployeeDemographics;
    RETURN cur;
END;
$$;
```

Then I tried to delete the saved functions using the following:

```
DROP FUNCTION get_employee_demographics(refcurser);
DROP FUNCTION select_all_employee_demographics;
```

But I get the following errors:

> "could not find a function named "select_all_employee_demogrphics"

Please also see attached image of my environment.

Please let me know if i need to specify further.

Comment: Just DROP FUNCTION select_all_employee_demographics(); -- function without input

Comment: Related docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropfunction.html. Are you sure that the function exists? Did you maybe already drop it?

Comment: Looks like a spelling/typing error: *demogrphics* is not the same as *demographics*. The error message does not correspond to the drop statement: "could not find function named select_all_employee_demogrphics" vs statement posted "drop function select_all_employee_demographics;"

Comment: yes you are correct - i fixed the spelling error: demogrphics to demographics.

then used: "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS public.select_all_employee_demographics(refcursor);"

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop the function without inputs, like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION select_all_employee_demographics();
```

references: [PostgreSQL Drop Function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-plpgsql/postgresql-drop-function/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS public.select_all_employee_demographics(refcursor);
```

This piece of code worked, specific to my issue.

Thank you all for helping - appreciate it